# JQuery binding to document click handler on object click triggers document click handler immediately

Tags: jquery, click, document, bind, handler

I wrote a click handler that creates a binding to the document click handler like so:

```
$("#button").bind('click',function(){

    ....


    $(document).bind('click',function(){           
      console.log("document.click");
    });
});
```

What I find strange about this is that the document click handler fires and I get the console log immediately. In other words, I get the console log the very first time I click #button. Is this because it takes time for the click to bubble up to the document, and I'm binding to the document click event just before it gets there? Is there any way to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
$("#button").bind('click',function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    ....


    $(document).bind('click',function(){           
      console.log("document.click");
    });
});
```

This will prevent the event from bubbling up